# Cubic Differentiation for $g(x) = x^3+2x-10$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I was told to solve for $x$ in $g(x) = x^3+2x-10$ using the cubic equation here (https://math.vanderbilt.edu/schectex/courses/cubic/).

So I took $a = 1, b = 0, c = 2, d = -10$, plugged into the cubic formula and got $x =$$(5+\sqrt{\frac{683}{27}})^{\frac{1}{3}} + (5-\sqrt{\frac{683}{27}})^{\frac{1}{3}}$. 
Then I take the derivative, $g'(x) = 3x^2 +2$ and plug what I have from x up above into g'(x). That gets me $3((5+\sqrt{\frac{683}{27}})^{\frac{2}{3}}+(5-\sqrt{\frac{683}{27}})^{\frac{2}{3}}+2(25-\frac{683}{27})^{\frac{1}{3}})+2$. That's about $11.8$ in WolframAlpha. Then, I took the inverse derivative rule, which was finding $\frac {d} {dx} [f^{-1}(8)]$. I got $\frac{1}{14}$, which is nowhere close to $11.8$. I could really use some help.

Comment: There ought to be three solutions for $x$ since $g(x)$ is not a perfect cube.

Comment: @SimpleArt How do I find the other two?

Comment: @SimpleArt - I don't follow. $x^3 = 27$ has three solutions, as does $x^3  = 1$.

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 Yes.  I am pointing out that the other two roots are not mentioned.

Comment: @MathisLife use the quadratic formula after some factoring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wanted was a function that gives $x$ in terms of $g(x)$.  So you should have taken $d = -10 - g$ in your cubic formula.

This gives three awful-looking roots, one of which is real (it is easy to tell that the equation has only one real root, because the first derivative of $g(x)$ is never zero so the function is always increasing).

$$ x(g) = \frac{\left(90+9g+\sqrt{81g^2+1620g+8196}\right)^{1/3}}{\sqrt[3]{18}}
- \frac{\sqrt{16/3}}{\left(90+9g+\sqrt{81g^2+1620g+8196}\right)^{1/3}}
$$

Now you should proceed by taking the derivative of that messy root with respect to $g$, finding the reciprocal of that expression, plugging in $g=x^3+2x-10$, and simplifying, hopfully getting $\frac{dg}{dx} = 3x^2+2$.

Even full Mathematica does not perform this simplification automagically; you have to guide and coax it!

Comment: Haha, auto**magically**

Comment: I'm still kind of confused on why I would set d = -10-g.

Comment: if $g=x^3 + 2x -10$ then $$x^3 + 2x +(-10-g) = 0$$